# How to input in C#

Tags: c#

How to input in C#? and using loop on that input.

Here is my code so far i trying

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
 {

            int[] ar = new int[10002];
            int n = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );

            for( int i = 0;i < n; i++ )
            {
                ar[i] = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ar[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

   }
```

Comment: What isn't working so far?

Comment: It's show error message like as "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: You have to give an integer as input. That's why the error is showing. You are probably giving a string containing non-numeric characters.

Comment: `ten` for example does not work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of two ways of handling the invalid input in your case. One thing you can do, is just fail giving the user an information that the input was not correct. Second possibility is to treat invalid input as a `null` value.

This is just a simple example - usually you shouldn't fail silently (here: return a `null` and not complain), and you shouldn't use `null` values as an indicator for a special function return value. Also a good example would be not to finish the program but use a loop to ask the user repeatedly until they learn how a number looks like ;)

These all issues are left unsolved as a practice for the reader ;)

```
static int? ReadInteger()
{
    int result;

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)   
{
    int?[] ar = new int?[10002];
    int? n = ReadInteger();

    if (!n.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please input a correct integer");
        return;
    }

    for( int i = 0;i < n.Value; i++ )
    {
        ar[i] = ReadInteger();
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n.Value; i++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ar[i].HasValue
            ? ar[i].Value.ToString() : "Incorrect input");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: int?[] ? Really? Maybe it's legitimate in this case, but the expression makes me feel ill :)

Comment: Bear in mind that it's a simple example for a newcomer :)

Comment: I did bear that in mind, which is why you got an upvote, despite the nausea :)

Comment: @DavidArno :) Thanks for your feedback, I updated the answer, to make it clear that the problem in general should be solved in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build this as close as possible to your implementation. The other answer from BartoszKP should be used in a complete scenario.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ar = new int[10002];
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
        {
            int nr;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {                
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr))
                {
                    ar[i] = nr;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ar[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Your code don't take input ( good way ). Like as n = 3, then it's should be take three number 1 2 3 like that but your code take three input new line wise, so i think it's problem

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The code does what it's supposed to. If you're saying that it reads another line at the end, that's because of the Console.ReadKey(), used by you probably to stop the console from closing at the end of the execution.